# Generating types out of vue-router route[x].name

Tags: typescript, vue.js, types, vue-router

i am trying to generate route names from the routes of vue router.
the goal is to use a helper function `findRouteByName()` to find a route.

but the parameters of the helper function should have the real `route.name` as types.
When I try to do this I get the following error:

```
The type 'readonly [{ readonly path: "/"; readonly name: "Root"; readonly children: readonly []; },
{ readonly path: "/somePath"; readonly name: "somePath1"; readonly component: "Blub"; readonly
 children: readonly []; }, { readonly path: "/somePath2"; readonly name: "somePath2"; readonly 
component: "Blub"; readonly children: ...' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 
'RouteRecordRaw[]'.(4104)
```

but there is a way...

example:
[image: route types]

the example in the picture works only if I don't give the routes the type `RouteRecordRaw[]`.

Then I can achieve my goal and use the types in the function as parameters.

But I must and should give `RouteRecordRaw[]` as type for routes. Otherwise there will be a complaint when the router is initialized.
So it should work with `RouteRecordRaw[]`.

I have prepared everything here on Stackblitz, maybe one of you will find an elegant solution for this.

#### [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-jfxhz3?file=src%2Frouter%2Findex.ts&terminal=dev)

Answer (score 0):

Try `satisfies RouteRecordRaw[]` instead of `as const`.

You'll get the same type deduction, but ts won't yell at you for the extra `readonly`s

Comment: then errors are gone but i have no type suggestions based on the route names

Comment: Even when the array is wrapped in parentheses?

Comment: have u make it run?

Comment: I've noticed your stackblitz was a bit different than the picture you posted. Your issue was with type hinting it routes with `RouteRecordRaw[]` which didn't add anything, as seen here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-blf3hp?file=src%2Frouter%2Findex.ts&terminal=dev

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach to make sure that all the types are satisfied and yet you get intellisense for `findRouteByName` -

`router/index.ts`

```ts
import {
  RouteRecordRaw,
  _RouteRecordBase,
  createRouter,
  createWebHistory,
} from "vue-router";

type ForceMergeTypes<T, K> = T | (K & Record<never, never>);

type Paths = "/" | "somePath" | "somePath2";
type Names = "Root" | "somePath" | "somePath2";

type ExtendedRouteRecordBase = _RouteRecordBase & {
  path: ForceMergeTypes<Paths, RouteRecordRaw["path"]>;
  name?: ForceMergeTypes<Names, RouteRecordRaw["name"]>;
};

type RoutesRecord = ExtendedRouteRecordBase & RouteRecordRaw;

const routes: Array<RoutesRecord> = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Root",
    component: null,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    path: "/somePath",
    name: "somePath1",
    component: null,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    path: "/somePath2",
    name: "somePath2",
    component: null,
    children: [],
  },
];

export function findRouteByName(name: (typeof routes)[number]["name"]) {
  return routes.find((route) => route.name === name);
}

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

findRouteByName("");

export default router;
```

With this approach, you can provide any string for `path` & `name` and yet get intellisense for the string you add to types `Path` and `Names`. Let me know if I missed something or if doesn't meet your requirements.

[image: Example]

**Note:** you may not get intellisense in Stackblitz with this, however, you'll get it in your IDE, like VSCode. That's just so, because of Stackblitz limitation.

Comment: thanks for the effort but it's not what i try to do.
1. you decuple the names so they become redundant.
2. the expected result of type suggestion inside the "findRouteByName" function is not given.